# R: copy string to column if contained in another column

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I have a database (structured according to dplyr principle) giving an overview of a literature database. One of the columns is "language", and another one is "tag", a deprecated column I'd like to clean up as it contains multiple information. It also contains "language" information.

Each book entry has its language in that "tag" entry (along with other information, separated by commas). How can I copy each of these language strings contained in "tag" to the respective language column (currently empty).

I.e., how can I do "if tag column contains string "English" then move "English" to column "language"?

Comment: probably use `grepl`, however there's nothing much anyone can say without reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe with `dputs(dataframe)`

Answer (score 0):

```
db<-data.frame(tags=c("Moose, English", "Feet, French"), language=NA)

db$language<-ifelse(grepl("English", db$tags), "English", db$language)
db$language<-ifelse(grepl("French", db$tags), "French", db$language)
```

This has the disadvantage of requiring you to know all the possible languages in the tags columns. You might want to run this when you're done to identify any left over languages:

```
db$tags[is.na(db$language)]
```

This will give you the tags from all the cases where no language was assigned yet.

UPDATE: A slightly simplified version will use a for loop through a vector with all the language names:

```
languages<-c("English","French","Spanish"[...])
for (i in 1:length(languages)) {
  db$language<-ifelse(grepl(languages[i], db$tags), languages[i], db$language)
}
```

Both options return

```
            tags language
1 Moose, English  English
2   Feet, French   French
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl` to check if a string contains something.

For example:

```
tag <- c('Containing English Information', 'Containing unknown information')
testdata <- data.frame(tag)
testdata$language <- ifelse(grepl("English", testdata$tag), "English", NA)
testdata
```

returns

```
                             tag language
1 Containing English Information  English
2 Containing unknown information     <NA>
```

Comment: Note that if you repeat this with different languages, `NA` will be imputed into $language which doesn't contain the current language every time you run it. To avoid this, replace NA with `testdata$language` as I suggested below.

Comment: @doviod Ah you are right, that was a sloppy answer by me